# question about "Norm"

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

i have this space $H=\lbrace u\in AC([0,+\infty), u(0)=u(+\infty)=0, \sqrt{p}u'\in L^2((0,+\infty))\rbrace$ where $p>0$ and $\displaystyle\frac1p\in L^1$

how to see that the quantity: $\displaystyle||u||^2=\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} p(t)u'^2(t) dt$ is a norm ?

i have $||u||=0$ impliese that $u'(t)=0$  why $u=0$ ?

Thank you

Comment: If $u' \equiv 0$, what does that imply about $u$? Then look at the boundary conditions.

Comment: if u'=0 then u is a constant for all t, we replace by 0 then the constant equal 0 ?

Comment: Yes. $u$ is then a constant function, and $u(0) = 0$ is part of the requirements.

Comment: $u(0)=0$ is sufficient or we must use $u(+\infty)=0$ ? thank you

Comment: Either of the two conditions alone is sufficient to conclude that the only constant function in $H$ is $0$.